# Having trouble with Japanese text in PHPUnit

Tags: utf-8, phpunit, non-english

I have a ZF2 application that uses a lot of Japanese. I'm trying to test the output of things such as people's names and addresses. But when I try to run `$this->assertQueryContentContains()` with DOM elements containing Japanese characters, the tests fail. What's more, the output in the console shows characters that are completely different from the ones I used. For example, I ran the following test:

```
$this->assertQueryContentContains('span#address', '<strong>Address:</strong> 〒300-1234 茨城県つくば市上郷１－２－３');
```

The output of the console showed this:

```
Failed asserting node denoted by span#address CONTAINS content  "<strong>Address:</strong> 縲・00-1234縲闌ｨ蝓守恁縺､縺上・蟶ゆｸ企・・托ｼ搾
```

As you can see (assuming your browser can properly display Japanese), the characters being output are completely different from the ones that I actually entered, which leads me to believe there's some kind of setting I need to set to allow testing utf-8. The test unit's file is encoded in utf-8 without BOM (via Notepad++).

Comment: Assign the expected content and the actual node content to vars and echo them. Maybe the console is not handling UTF-8 properly.

Answer (score 0):

May you try to use mb_convert_encoding function in your assert function
Eg:

```
$this->assertQueryContentContains('span#address', mb_convert_encoding('<strong>Address:</strong> 〒300-1234 茨城県つくば市上郷１－２－３',"SJIS"));
```